# Is there any way to install any apk via a custom launcher in Meta Quest 2?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, launcher

I'm working on a project that involves building a launcher. Once installed, the launcher will grant users access to all the VR games I develop. Initially, I developed this launcher for PICO, and it worked seamlessly due to PICO's API support. However, I'm facing a challenge with the Quest platform. Unlike PICO, there doesn't seem to be a straightforward method to install games on Quest, as it requires either the Oculus Store, App Lab or SideQuest for installation.

I attempted to find a way to install games from SideQuest programmatically, but it seems that it may not be possible.

I also tried with this but it didn't work either:

```
public void InstallApp(string apkPath, Action<int> instalationCallback)
{
    AndroidJavaClass intentClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.content.Intent");
    AndroidJavaObject intentObject = new AndroidJavaObject("android.content.Intent");

    string uriString = apkPath;
    AndroidJavaObject uriObject = new AndroidJavaObject("android.net.Uri", uriString);

    intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setAction", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("ACTION_VIEW"));
    intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setDataAndType", uriObject, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");

    AndroidJavaClass unityPlayerClass = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
    AndroidJavaObject unityActivityObject = unityPlayerClass.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");

    unityActivityObject.Call("startActivity", intentObject);


}
```